# Uninitialized constant in query with joins

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, join

Hi I want to use joins to match two entities.

Expected result:

```
select sum(price) from entry_types inner join bought_details on entry_types.id = bought_details.entry_type_id
```

Now I have:

```
@sum_earnings = EntryType.joins(:bought_details).sum(:price)
```

There is a error:

```
uninitialized constant EntryType::BoughtDetail
```

Schema information:

```
# Table name: bought_details
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  bought_data   :date             not null
#  end_on        :date             not null
#  entry_type_id :integer
#  person_id     :integer
#  start_on      :date

# Table name: entry_types
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  kind         :string           not null
#  kind_details :string           not null
#  description  :text
#  price        :decimal(5, 2)    not null
```

How to resolve this problem? What does mean this error? Thanks in advance.

Models:

```
class Backend::EntryType < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :bought_details
end

class Backend::BoughtDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :entry_type
end
```

Comment: Do you have `BoughtDetail` model and a defined relation between `BoughtDetail` and `EntryType`?

Comment: @Babar updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you defined your @sum_earnings ?

Have you tried writing

```
Backend::EntryType.joins(:bought_details).sum(:price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Models are namespaced. Try explicitly mentioning the classes with the relations:

```
class Backend::EntryType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bought_details, class_name: 'Backend::BoughtDetail'
end

class Backend::BoughtDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry_type, class_name: 'Backend::EntryType'
end
```